# How did succession work in the modern Argentine military dictatorships?

Tags: military, dictatorship

For example, it says on the wikipedia page for [Alfredo Oscar Saint Jean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfredo_Oscar_Saint_Jean), an Argentine president and general: "Saint-Jean's brief period as President in June and July 1982 ended when he was succeeded by General Reynaldo Bignone."

How does that work? Does the military have some kind of election? Does the General get to appoint his successor?

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the internal laws of the country? Argentina had a military Junta, so yes, the generals of the three armies voted.

Comment: I guess so. I'll edit the question to be specific to Argentina, because although I think the question kinda works, tbh I am interested in this information for purposes related to Argentina.

Comment: @AlbertoYagos Well, the first part of the answer would be explaining if there was a formal system with laws establishing the procedures or if it was more of an informal system.